# Getting around lack of support for List in Native Query in clauses in openJPA

Tags: openjpa

I have no idea why any one would do this (include support for Lists in named queries but not native named queries (and believe me when I tell you I am steaming mad about this).  How can one get around this flaw?  I can't possibly put all the place values for the array into the native query,  It could be up to several hundred units long!!!!!  How would you handle this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem that you're having?

Comment: Nothing else really to comment on... I tried to do a NamedNativeQuery with an in clause and an ArrayList as the parameter.  However, I get an exception telling me that an arrayList is not an excepted type.  Imagine my consternation as it is an excepted type with just NamedQueries.  I am currently going through all kinds of machinations to do the exact same thing that I could have done assuming that simple logic had been inclueded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pass a List as a parameter to a normal SQL statement? No.

```
 /**
 * Create an instance of Query for executing a native SQL statement, e.g., for update or delete.
 * @param sqlString a native SQL query string
 * @return the new query instance
 */ 
 public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString);
```

When you create a native query, the JPA provider will blindly pass that SQL to the database and it assumes the user has formatted the SQL appropriately.

If you want to pass a List as a query parameter, use JPQL.

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was writing a nativeNamedQuery and building the In clause with a foreach loop and a Or In clause if the 'index % 1000 = 0' (essentially if it is a factor of 1000).